# How to install Ubuntu from within other Linux Distributions without reboot

Tags: system-installation

I have an OpenSuse Linux running on my work pc. I have no time to go offline and install Ubuntu. Ideally I want to mount ubuntu.iso, run Ubuntu Installer from bash, and then, at the evening, just reboot, select Ubuntu from grub, and decide whether i stay with it.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a procedure to install Ubuntu offline (without rebooting) from your current Linux system. I do not think, It is better to include all the details here.

You can check the exact procedure [for 14.04](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/installation-guide/i386/apds04.html) / [for 16.04](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/installation-guide/i386/apds04.html) from Ubuntu Installation Guide

I have recently tried that and installed Kubuntu 12.04. It worked flawlessly.

It requires at least one reboot, to open your newly installed system. You can't switch from one OS to another without rebooting

---

Reference: [Ubuntu Installation Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/installation-guide/amd64/index.html)

Comment: link no longer there

Comment: For 14.04, updated guide is [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/installation-guide/i386/index.html)

Comment: Exact link here for the UNetbootin Hard Disk Install mode: https://sourceforge.net/p/unetbootin/wiki/installmodes/

Comment: Link does not work anymore. Here is a new one. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/apds04.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use it virtual machines. You can install **oracle virtual box** on your OpenSUSE machine and then download a ubuntu iso (not then default one) but one that has the image of virtual machine. And now you are ready to rock and roll!